# Sorting DataGrid while animating cells causes exception

Tags: .net, wpf

I have created an DataGridCell template that I have applied to one of my columns like so:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastUpdated}" 
    IsReadOnly="True" CanUserReorder="False" 
    CanUserSort="False" CanUserResize="False"
    CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle1}" 
 />
```

And the template looks like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
   <ControlTemplate.Resources>
      <Storyboard x:Key="CellChangedStoryboard">
          <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="DGC_Border">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="LightGreen"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:8" Value="Red"/>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      </Storyboard>
  </ControlTemplate.Resources>
   <Border x:Name="DGC_Border" Background="Red">
       <ContentPresenter />
         <i:Interaction.Triggers>
               <ei:TimerTrigger MillisecondsPerTick="1000" >
                     <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource CellChangedStoryboard}"/>
               </ei:TimerTrigger>
         </i:Interaction.Triggers>
     </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

In this example I am triggering the anim using a Blend TimerTrigger, but it doesnt matter how I trigger my animation, it always crashes as soon as I try to sort my DataGrid (by clicking on one of the column headers)

If I remove the storyboard then it does not crash on sort.

The exception is **InvalidOperationException: 'DGC_Border' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.Border'.**

I suspect that when the DataGrid sorts it destroys or otherwise messes with the cells/columns and the animation which is running can no longer find the cell it was animating.

Why is the exception happening and how do I stop it?
Thanks

Update: Seems to work Ok if I use `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>` to trigger the StoryBoard. Unfortunately this is no solution as I need to play the storyboard when a bound property changes.

Comment: Are you trying to essentially recreate the Validation UI but with animation?

Comment: Nope, just want to animate my cells when they update

Answer (score 0):

Best I could come up with was to ditch the Blend triggers and use this:

```
<Border x:Name="DGC_Border" Background="Red">
                        <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                          Content="{Binding LastUpdated, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
                            <ContentPresenter.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource RowChangedStoryboard}" />
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </ContentPresenter.Triggers>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
```

I notice that after the grid sorts all the animations are removed, which is not correct behavior for me - I want the animations to continue from exactly where they left off but I will have to save that for another day.